# Error Messages as Key Value Pairs - from a Properties File in classpath - Spring boot 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are currently on a Spring Boot Version 1.x

We have Error Messages (Error Key -> Error Code) pairs in our error.properties file (this is in the class path).

We leveraged [PropertiesConfigurationFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/bind/PropertiesConfigurationFactory.html) to get these Error Key and Error Code pairs in to a POJO, this POJO had a Map

Hence very convenient to be used across our application to get an Error code for a given Error Key.

What is its equivalent in Spring Boot 2.x ?.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `error.properties` file with the below contents:

```
errors.error1=101
errors.error2=102
errors.error3=103
```

A simple spring boot app that demonstrates the injection of these properties :

```
package snmaddula.remittance;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:error.properties")
public class DemoApplication {

    private Map<String, Integer> errors;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner cli() {
        return (args) -> {
            System.out.println(errors); // you can print and see the error properties injected to this map.
        };
    }

    public void setErrors(Map<String, Integer> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

}
```

With the use of `@PropertySource` and `@ConfigurationProperties` we can enable property injection provided we have a `setter` method for our attribute.

When you run this program, you can see the properties getting printed on to the console as I added a `CommandLineRunner cli() {..}` to show the working of it.

The working sample is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/snmaddula-stackoverflow/56032124).